# Is there a formal way to return True or False in MIPS assembly language?

Tags: mips, mips32, mips64

Or is printing 1 when a function evaluates to True and printing -1 when a function is false acceptable?

Comment: Usuall convention is : zero as false, any Nonzero as true.

Comment: ok thanks bud. So is printing zero to signifiy false and printing everything that is non-zero as true sufficient?

Comment: I do not know what you mean "print". If you print something in the screen just print "The condition is true". Functions return "return  values"